# Combining controller and loop variables in forEach loop

Tags: angularjs, foreach

Having just started with AngularJS, i can't get my head around this. I'm sure there is a very simple solution or just something wrong with my syntax.

I want to use the varibale 'day' from the main controller in the forEach loop along with 'item' variable. So it loops through each product and updates the relevant day to true or false, but 'day' isn't been picked up when on item.day.

```
vm.selectAllTemplateDays = function (day, selectProduct) {

        vm.suppliedProducts = [];

        var currentTemplate = $filter('filter')(vm.productTemplate, vm.searchString);

        currentTemplate.forEach(function (item) {

            item.day = selectProduct;

        });

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciaited

Comment: Put console.log(currentTemplate) before var currentTemplate = $filter('filter')(vm.productTemplate, vm.searchString); and look console of browser, then put the message here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're missing a `condition` before assigning the value. Try below sinppet

```
currentTemplate.forEach(function (item) {
   if(item.day == day)
      item.day = selectProduct;
});
```